# Can I use FCM after my app deleted from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app will be deleted after 9th Mar. because my app no longer supports Google Play policy.
I am afraid that the users that have already installed my app will not be able to receive Push notification.

Can I use FCM after my app has been deleted from Google Play ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

FCM is not tied to the Google play listing, the registration to FCM is done from the application when loaded.

As push notifications can be sent to ad-hoc applications, you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fcm while development without publishing your app on play store so its not relation b/w fcm and play store.